# On click of icon open jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

In backbone view, I have following code in html

```
<input type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate"/><a id="cal">
<img src="img/calendar.gif"></a>
```

In view's js file, I have the following code:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!views/page1/page1.tpl'], function($, _, Backbone, tmpl_page1View) {

var page1View = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Setting the view's template property using the Underscore template method        
    template: _.template(tmpl_page1View),
    // View constructor
    initialize: function() {
        self = this;

    },
    // View Event Handlers
    events: {
        "click #page2": "clickedPage2",
        "click #cal":"calClicked"
    },
    // Renders the view's template to the UI
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({data: this.templateData}));           
        // Maintains chainability
        return this;
    },
    clickedPage2:function(){
        window.location.href = "#page2"
    },
    calClicked:function(){
       $("#fromDate").datepicker({
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
          buttonImageOnly: true
        });

    }

});
return page1View;
});
```

On click event of calendar icon, I want to open datepicker but it is not working. Can you help me on this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize datepicker e.g. in `render` method, and datepicker will open automatically on button click, so you won't need `calClicked` at all.

```
var page1View = Backbone.View.extend({
// Setting the view's template property using the Underscore template method        
template: _.template(tmpl_page1View),
// View constructor
initialize: function() {
    self = this;

},
// View Event Handlers
events: {
    "click #page2": "clickedPage2",
    "click #cal":"calClicked"
},
// Renders the view's template to the UI
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({data: this.templateData}));  

    // init datepicker
    this.$("#fromDate").datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });


    // Maintains chainability
    return this;
},
clickedPage2:function(){
    window.location.href = "#page2"
}    

});
return page1View;
});
```